# Compare two columns on different excel files

Tags: excel

I have two Excel files A and B. File A has a column Loan ID which are unique and File B has column loan ID which are repeatable and these loan IDs are from file A.

Now I need to identify any loan id which is not present in both the files. Do you have any trick for this?

Thanks
Vikram

Comment: Try searching stackoverflow `[excel] compare columns`

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B1:B5000B,A1)>0,"",A1)
```

The Final A1 represents the Column `Loan ID` value to return if the Value is not found in column B

[image: Excel with two columns one the base column and one to find missing values in.]